# What is causing this CorelDraw VBA Macro Mismatch Error?

Tags: excel, vba, coreldraw

I have a short Excel VBA macro that takes the current selection in an (open) CorelDraw drawing and moves it. Why am I getting a mismatch runtime error when I set `OrigSelection` to be the `app.ActiveSelectionRange`? Here is my code:

```
Private Sub MoveAndResizeSelection()
    Dim app As CorelDraw.Application
    Set app = CorelDraw.Application
    Dim OrigSelection As ShapeRange
    Set OrigSelection = app.ActiveSelectionRange
    
    'Move and Resize the selection
    OrigSelection.Move 2.595, -6.751
    
End Sub
```

I am using Excel Office 16 and CorelDraw Graphics Suite 2022.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the variable ```OrigSelection``` and directly moving ```app.ActiveSelectionRange.Move```. Not sure what was originally causing the problem though.

Comment: Most likely `Dim OrigSelection As CorelDraw.ShapeRange` I'm guessing. `Dim OrigSelection As ShapeRange` is implicitly `Dim OrigSelection As Excel.ShapeRange`, but you're not working with an Excel `ShapeRange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is

```
Dim OrigSelection As ShapeRange
```

which is implicitly

```
Dim OrigSelection As Excel.ShapeRange
```

Change to

```
Dim OrigSelection As CorelDraw.ShapeRange
```